# Updating Series Color Appears to Break Navigator and Range Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

We want to allow for the users to change the colors of the series from a monochrome-type gradient to divergent colors. We are doing this via a drop down menu and we capture their selection and do the update like below (simpler code than demo):

```
var rainbow = new Rainbow();
// Set start and end colors
rainbow.setSpectrum('#528bc2', 'white');
// Set the min/max range
var numSeries = chart.series.length;
var rangeLow = 0;
var rangeHigh = numSeries
rainbow.setNumberRange(rangeLow, rangeHigh);

// Loop over data and update the color value
for (index = 0; index < numSeries; ++index) {
    if (chart.series[index].name != 'Navigator') {
        if (chart.series[index].options.yAxis == 1) {
            chart.series[index].update({
                color: '#000080'
            }, false);
    } else {
        chart.series[index].update({
            color: '#' + rainbow.colourAt(index)
        }, false);
    }
    if (chart.series[index].visible) {
        var navigator = chart.get('nav');
        navigator.setData(chart.series[index].options.data);
    }
}
```

This does update the colors correctly and I can revert the change to use another list of colors in an array when the user wants to change back.

The chart is loaded up such that only one series is visible at a time and that series is used in the navigator series. When a user clicks on a series in the legend it hides the other series from being plotted and only shows the selected series, updates the navigator series, and updates the chart title. This works just fine when user does not change the color.

The issue I am facing is that when a user is on a series other than the initially loaded series when they change the color then the navigator series is reverted back to the series[0] data set because of `chart.redraw()` being called. How can I cleanly get the navigator series to be the currently visible series after calling the update code? I have tried putting this code (or similar block) after the color update and `chart.events.load` with no visible affect:

```
for (i = 0; i < this.series.length; i += 1) {
    if (this.series[i].name != 'Navigator') {
        if (this.series[i].visible) {
        console.log(this.series[i].name);
        var navigator = this.get('nav');
        navigator.setData(this.series[i].options.data);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a live set of data to work with in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/yct6y11m/).
To reproduce issue let chart load, then click on 'Data Trend (%)' in legend so that it is visible in the chart. Notice that the navigator series has changed to be this series. Now, in the drop down change the selected value to "Multi-color". Notice how the series' color has changed, but so has the navigator series data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigator has two properties which refer to series. The first one is its own series object - you update its data property, the second one is baseSeries which keeps reference to the main series from a chart.
http://jsfiddle.net/1jz3r78v/1/

If you set baseSeries to a visible series it works as you expected.

```
            serie[i].show();
            var navigator = this.chart.get('nav');
            this.chart.scroller.baseSeries = this; // serie[i]
            navigator.setData(serie[i].options.data);
            this.chart.setTitle({
              text: serie[i].name
            });
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/yct6y11m/1/

Comment: Okay, this appears to work on the first go. However, when you click to series 4, change to multi-color, click on series 2, then click on series 4 again it no longer obeys the set zoom range (from the buttons at the top or by using navigator series zoom handles) - it always is set to view all of the xAxis. If you click on series 1 it then cleans up and the navigator zoom setting is obeyed.

Comment: I reduced a number of redrawing in your code - seems to not having the zooming issue anymore: https://jsfiddle.net/yct6y11m/2/ Basically on every legendClick the chart redraws a few times - hide, show for every series, setTitle, setData - it is better to call once redraw after all changes are made.

Comment: Ack, yea, those are live in my main code. Forgot to clean up from my jsfiddle. Thank you.